# How to remove R rated movies from TheMovieDatabase API

Tags: node.js, api, themoviedb-api, profanity, data-filtering

i am working with [theMovieDatabase api](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/)

I want to get the movies by name, luckily the functionality for that is working perfectly but now i am trying to add profanity to the data that i get back, some of the data is clearly 18+, but the adult property that i get back in the data always shows false, i have tried using different query like

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${name}&page=1&include_adult=false&certification_country=IN&certification.lte=UA
```

but it's not working, if any of you have worked with the API in the past, your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: discover endpoint has this capability but it doest allow the search query it seems

Comment: @cmgchess yeah, i don't understand the thought process of the Devs who made this